# Concatenated string to date conversion

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I am doing something like this,
i have two columns month and year and i want to create a new column which will be in mm/dd/yyy fromat. so in my case mm is month column , yyyy is year column and date is default 01.

```
update [tablename]
set period= convert(date,month+'/01/'+year)
```

now i want this period to be in date data type, i am doing:

```
alter table [tablename]
alter column period date
```

but it is giving me error that string can't be converted to date.
If anyone could help that will be very helpful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have bad data in your table. Since you didn't use the right data type in the first place, you could have *anything at all* in the `month`/`year` columns, since there is no built in validation that month is 1-12 and year is in the valid range of values. For example, someone could have put 99 in month and -213 in year.

Do this:

```
SELECT period FROM dbo.tablename WHERE ISDATE([month] + '/01/' + [year]) = 0;
```

This should identify the rows you need to fix. If this returns the whole table, or returns values that you think should be dates, then show a few examples. The syntax in your update doesn't look right (at the very least missing a `+`) so I'm not sure what you actually ran against your table, but that's not it. Also a much safer format would be:

```
SET period = [year] + [month] + '01';
```

This is because what you are using now, `mm/dd/yyyy`, is not safe from regional, language and dateformat settings. `06/05/2013` could be interpreted as May 6th instead of June 5th, and `11/13/2012` could return an error because SQL Server doesn't know of any 13th month. [Loads of details here](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/16/bad-habits-to-kick-mis-handling-date-range-queries).

And you don't need to convert it to date first. Just do that with the ALTER - converting it to date does little for you when it's still stored as a string...

Comment: the "+" in my question was missing due to typing error, and also i agree with you that mm/dd/yyyy is not safe format. but as per my requirement i nedd final data in this format only.

Comment: @PiyushBhardwaj "final data in this format" sounds like you should be using that format only in the presentation tier, where you client language has the ability to present a date value in any string format you want. C# has .Format() and .ToString(), for example, which can do whatever you want without ever treating these dates as strings anywhere in the database layer.

Comment: by final data i mean that in my table i want to store data in mm/dd/yyyy format.

Comment: @Piyush no, you don't. You're storing a ***DATE***, not a date in some specific format, which is just a string. You lose so, so much by storing a date as a string, you really don't want to do that. And if you don't want to take my advice, then just leave the column as a varchar or whatever it is now. You ***CANNOT*** have a `DATE` column that is stored in your favorite format - they're simply not stored as strings at all.

Comment: and also the period column should be of date type.

Comment: i agree with what all you said, i tell you what my real issue is. I want to concatenate two strings in the way i asked in question, and then store that string in date data type column(i.e alter that string column to date). is it possible ?

Comment: No, it is not possible. Like I said, `DATE` does not store any specific string format; it actually stores a different type of value altogether. And I really, really, really do not understand why you think you want/need to store a specific format anyway. Do you care *how* SQL Server stores January 13th, 2013? Why?

Comment: Ok,i think i dint explain why i need to convert period column to date data type. because string is not the valid format in the tool which i am using, if the column is not date type it wont populate in the list. and also i dont want to store in any specific format, i just want that it should be of date type

Comment: @PiyushBhardwaj So just store it as a date and stop fussing on and on about format. If "the tool" you are using doesn't understand it, that's not a reason to change your database schema, that's a reason to figure out why the tool is having a problem.

Comment: but for a date datatype i can not concatenate two strings.

Comment: @PiyushBhardwaj I have no idea what you mean: `DECLARE @x DATE = '2010' + '-03-' + '01'; SELECT @x;`